# Bring Android emulator to front on installing APK in Windows

Tags: android, android-studio

In Windows, are there any way to bring the Android emulator to front automatically after installing the APK from Android Studio? (i.e without using alt-tab key manually)

Comment: I'm afraid that there is no option to do that. You might be wanting it as you have seen it in IOS simulator right?

Comment: @mhanifa you can set emulator to AlwaysStayOnTop so it will always be top of all

Comment: @UmangBurman i am not aware of the iOS simulator. but, i am glad that they have it

Comment: @AliAhmed yes, that's what i am doing now. i resize the Studio to 3/4 of the screen and the rest for the emulator.

Comment: Great! You can accept the answer for others help

Answer (score 0):

You can set **Emulator Always on Top** to achieve something similar.

**Steps to follow**

1. Run emulator on you computer.
2. Goto More option of Emulator. (Screenshot attached)
3. Goto Settings on newly popped up window, and enable Emulator always on top. (Screenshot attached)

**Step 2 Screenshot**

[image: Step 2]

**Step 3 Screen Shot**

[image: Step 3]